# Change the long click delay

Tags: mouse

Using the latest ubuntu, I often have the problem that the OS takes a usual click for a long click.

For example, when I (short) click on a Firefox tab, it will move this tab and create a new window with it.

I don't like it is because of me, I never had this problem before with MacOS or Windows. I'd like to change the long press delay, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Can you set the speed in Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad > Mouse Speed ?

Comment: Tested: it is the mouse move speed, not related to click duration

Comment: How about Settings > Universal Access > Pointing and Clicking > Double Click Delay pr experiment with Click Assist?

Comment: Click assist will throw a click in some conditions, and double click delay isn't the same delay :-(